# Can't add cookies in Phantomjs from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, phantomjs

I'm trying to load some cookies on the fly using PhantomJS, but I'm getting some errors. Here is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var cookieJson = require('cookie.json'); // local cookie file

phantom.cookiesEnabled = true; // Enable Cookies

phantom.clearCookies(); // Clear Old Cookies

for(var i = 0; i< cookieJson.length; i++) { //for each domain, try to add the cookie
    var temp = cookieJson[i];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));  // This seems to print just fine
    phantom.addCookie(temp); // this throws an exception
    }


phantom.exit();
```

The above code throws the following exception:

```
incompatible type of argument(s) in call to addCookie(); candidates were
    addCookie(QVariantMap)
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution here, but I'm having a brain freeze. I'm under the impression that `JSON.stringify` returns a string from a JSON object. What's really confusing is that when I print it to console, it appears exactly the same as if I stored it as a `String` . My data looks like this:

```
{"domain": ".sweatytacobo.com",
"expires": "Tue, 10 Jun 2014 16:37:46 GMT",
"expiry": ,
"httponly": false,
"name": "__utmz",
"path": "/",
"secure": false,
"value": "268881515.13222266.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"}
```

And when I use the above as a string, it adds without a problem. So why is my `JSON.Stringify` giving me problems?

EDIT:

According to the comments of the [PhantomJS source code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/4989445e714bb97fe49ef8c00ccbce8b6cfbfbb0/src/phantom.h) addCookie is passed a QVariantMap in the format:

```
 {
     *   "name"     : "cookie name (string)",
     *   "value"    : "cookie value (string)",
     *   "domain"   : "cookie domain (string)",
     *   "path"     : "cookie path (string, optional)",
     *   "httponly" : "http only cookie (boolean, optional)",
     *   "secure"   : "secure cookie (boolean, optional)",
     *   "expires"  : "expiration date (string, GMT format, optional)"
     * }
```

So shouldn't I be able to somehow pass a JSON object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. PhantomJS addCookie is very picky about the format of the cookie.

Basically in order to convert the JSON, you have to pull values by iterating over the JSON object. For example:

```
var cookieJson = require('cookiefile.json'); 
// load in the cookies in JSON format from file

for(var i = 0; i< cookieJson.length; i++) {
    var tempCookie = {}; 

    tempCookie["name"] = cookieJson[i]["name"];
    tempCookie["domain"] = cookieJson[i]["domain"];
    tempCookie["value"] = cookieJson[i]["value"];
    tempCookie["path"] = cookieJson[i]["path"];
    tempCookie["session"] = cookieJson[i]["session"];
    tempCookie["storeId"] = cookieJson[i]["storeId"];

    // Here we are adding the relevant values as needed and in the proper format

    var tempADD = {"domain": tempCookie["domain"],
    "expires": tempCookie["expires"],
    "expirationDate": 1402418266,
    "httpOnly": tempCookie["httpOnly"],
    "name": tempCookie["name"],
    "path": tempCookie["path"],
    "secure": tempCookie["secure"],
    "value": tempCookie["value"],
    "session": tempCookie["session"],
    "storeId": tempCookie["storeId"]};

    // Finally, we add the cookie. phantom.addCookie returns true if successful
    if(phantom.addCookie(tempADD)){
        console.log("Cookie Added!");
        } else {
        console.log("Cookie Failure: ");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tempADD)) // print the cookie which failed to load
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually assign the stringified version of the object back to the variable:

```
temp = JSON.stringify(temp);
```

Comment: Yep, I forgot this. But when I added this line of code it still throws the exception.